# Having Trouble Stopping PHP, Inserting HTML and JS, Then Restarting PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to insert some HTML and JS into an existing dynamic PHP page.

I felt that a `switch()` statement would be my best alternative.

Allow me to explain;

I have a switch statement embedded within a PHP page and when a certain condition is met I'm including an include().

Here's what my code looks like. (abbreviated)

Within my PHP file that displays the page;

```
switch($color)
{
case "Red":
include ('red_widgets.php');
break;
}
```

Then red_widgets.php looks like;

```
?>
<div class="Shadow">
<script language="JavaScript" src="AScriptThatDisplaysWidgets"></script></div>
<?php
```

But when I run the page, I'm getting `"?>"` outputted and not the JS.

This may be obvious to some of you but if you could share with me what I'm doing wrong I'd be most appreciative and I thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include, you're in HTML-mode.  Just omit the leading `?>` and the trailing `<?php` and that will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to "stop PHP". Just update the appropriate PHP/JS/HTML file and the next time you request it from the server it will deliver the updated file/script output to your browser.

As to not receiving the correct output you have an error in your code.

Is the `include` file surrounded by `<?php` and `?>` ?

Comment: Hi @Ed Heal, I'm sorry to over complicate or over simplify things but I don't know what to do with: "Just update the appropriate PHP/JS/HTML file" Could you provide an example of what I'm updating? Thanks!!

Comment: @StuartKaufman - You are editing a PHP (one assumes) i.e. updating it.

Comment: Hi @Ed Heal, The include file is exactly as I posted above (with the only exception being the name of the script) as I was keeping the  script details private as this is ad code.